# Golang vendor package with vendored sub-packages

Tags: go, govendor

**Situation:**

Let's assume I've a package called `mypackage`. It exposes one method called `Build()`, that returns a concrete struct exposed by a third party library called `thirdpartypackage`, e.g. like shown as follows:

```
package mypackage

import tpp "github.com/thirdpartycompany/thirdpartypackage"

func Build() *tpp.SharedStruct{
   //...implementation
}
```

The package that exposes `SharedStruct` is vendored inside `mypackage`, because I want to distribute it and make that package independent.

**Problem:**

After importing `mypackage` into another project and using `thirdpartypackage` in my (integration) tests, I'm getting the following error:

> cannot use XXXX (type
>   "github.com/mycompany/mymainproject/vendor/github.com/mycompany/mypackage/vendor/github.com/thirdcompany/thirdpartypackage-go".Token)
>   as type
>   "github.com/empatica/mycompany/vendor/github.com/thirdcompany/thirdpartypackage"

Basically the compiler is distinguishing the vendored third-party package inside my library and the vendored package that I put in my main project.

**Question:**

Are there ways to solve this issue, that are not removing the vendored dependencies from my library, like suggested [here](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/vendoring-and-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library/2010/6)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Vendoring works good for commands and less good for individual packages...

Comment: Can you give your exact directory structure your point is not clear

Comment: This is why most vendoring tool flatten the vendor directory.  Govendor does this by default, I'm not sure about other vendor tools.  The paradigm I've started using for our libraries intended for import (as opposed to apps themselves) is to add `/vendor/*/` to our `.gitignore`.  This ignores subfolders in `/vendor/`, but NOT files (like `vendor.json`, for govendor).  Govendor then gracefully handles flattening the dependency tree, and your error vanishes, because both packages are now using the same fully-qualified import path for the structure's package.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are missing is this point:

> Code below a directory named "vendor" is importable only by code in the directory tree rooted at the parent of "vendor", and only using an import path that omits the prefix up to and including the vendor element. ([go command](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories))

What I understand from your problem is your `mypackage` has vendor as its child, so when it's imported by any other package at same level, then for obvious reason they cannot see that vendored list.

You can understand this as being similar to a `protected` feature.

So if you want to use that version in any other package, then this `vendor` should be present at same level. For example

```
ParentDirectory
 > mypackage
 > otherpackage (this will be importing mypackage)
 > vendor (vendor should be present in here so that all children under ParentDirectory can access this)
```

I hope I am clear with my point.